# how can i add an icon to HTML nested in JS

Tags: reactjs, jsx, styled-components

I am trying to insert an icon into JSX. I have already imported the icon, but i have no idea on how to add it to the code.

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import * as materialOutlined from '@styled-icons/material-outlined'
import {Search} from '@styled-icons/material'

const Navbar = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <Nav>
      <Logo>
        <img href="/" width="70%" height="70%" src="../static/images/telsem.png"/>
      </Logo>
      <SearchP>
        <input class="search" type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search for...." />
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </SearchP>
      </Nav>
  );
};
```

---

```
"<button type="submit">Search</button>"  i want to change the Name Search into an icon
```

Comment: iv'e tried, when i do so it just shows me the code output in text and i'm using styled-components btw and it sometimes goes blank when i try other ways

Comment: `<button type="submit"><Search /></button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already imported the `Search` icon from styled-components. You just have to render it in the JSX code by typing it between curly braces, which evaluates JS code.

```
<button type="submit">{<Search/>}</button>
```

As it is a component, you render it as `<Search/>` and not only `Search`.

Comment: i need help, i can't style the icons that i have inserted, do you know how i can do so with styled-components??

Comment: Check this [styled-components guide](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics), they show how to apply custom styles. Maybe it helps!